# weighted distribution of revenue between different channels SQL

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables, one has the sales revenue and the session count and channel that lead to the sale. The other table has all the traffics from the start until the users' last visit to the site,including the one that leaded to the sale. example:

**Table 1**

```
userID | sale session |       channel       |  revenue 
--------------------------------------------------------
6652         7               EMAIL               52.00
6832         3               DIRECT              64.32
 .           .                 .                   . 
 .           .                 .                   .
```

**Table 2**

```
userID | sessions |       channel       |  
----------------------------------------------
6652        1         Paid Search
6652        2         Organic Search NB
6652        3         Organic Search NB
6652        4         Display RT
6652        5         SEA Search Brand
6652        6         EMAIL
6652        7         EMAIL
6652        8         DIRECT
```

We are using an attribution model to distribution the revenue between different channels.

If we have only one channel (one session) then 100% of the revenue goes to that specific channel.

If we have two channels (only one before the actual sale), we divide the revenue between this 2 channels.

If we have three or more channels, we give 40% to the first channel,40% to the second channel, and 20% to the rest of the channels in the between, combined.

In the end we sum all revenues divided by channels, to see how much a specific channel attributed to our total revenue.

In our example, "Paid Search" gets 40% of $52.00, "EMAIL" gets 40% and the 20% rest goes to the rest of the channels in between(2/5 for "Organic Search NB",1/5 for Display RT,1/5 for "SEA Search Brand" and 1/5 for "EMAIL").
the 8th session do not get anything since it happens when the sale is done!

I would be more than thankful, if anybody can offer a solution for this in SQL or any other kind of algorithm.

Comment: based on the result you have mentioned, it seems that in case, when you have 3+ channels 40% goes to the 1st (`"Paid Search"`) and and the last (`"EMAIL"`) channel, doesn't it?

Comment: the model is taken from google analytics, it is called position based. So as you said 40% for the 1st channel, 40% for the last and 20% is divided for the channels between.